# Asynchronous Socket connections in Python or Node

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, asynchronous, tornado

I am creating an application that basically has multiple connections to a third party Chat Streaming API(Socket based).

The way it works is - Every user has an account on my app and another account on the third party app. He gives me an access token for the third party chat app and I connect to the third party API to stream his chats. This happens for hundreds of users.

I need to create a socket connection pool for every user and run parallel threads. I am using a python library(for that API) and am able to achieve real time feeds for single users. How do I implement an asynchronous socket connection pool in Python or NodeJS? I have a Linux micro instance on EC2 and I need to run this application for 1000 users.

I am exploring Redis+Tornado to implement this. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: So basically your app should serve as a transparent proxy between the clients and the third party API?

Comment: @robertklep Sort of. It connects to a third party streaming API on behalf of the clients, and filters some data and stores it in my database.

Comment: Jquery(client side) not allowed `Socket based` ! All python MVC is wsgi based. So the distribution is not a good idea to use. My opinion : share user which is in a group, divide user port to location, `DB == io` so you need a lot ram for time-lapse recording, never use server-side data to compare, work with `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be messy and also a couple of things to consider.

1. If you are going to use multiple threads remember that you can only run so many per CPU as the OS permits, rather go [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).
2. If you are going async with long polling processes it will prevent other clients from processing requests.

**Solution**

When your application absolutely needs to be real-time I would suggest websockets for server-client interaction.

Then from your clients request start a single process that listens\polls on your streaming API using `multiprocessing` in python. So you will essentially create a separate process for each client.

And now, to make your `WebSocketHandler` and Background API Streamer interact with each other you can use the Observer Pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to notify the WebSocket that you have received data from the API.

Make sure that you assign a unique ID to every client and make sure that you only post the data to the intended client when using websockets.

**EDIT:**

*Web:*

Also on your question regarding Tornado. It is a good lightweight framework for running a couple of users maybe 1000. But anything more than that I would suggest looking at Django as it will allow you to be more productive in producing code and also there are lots of tools out there that the community have developed over time.

*Database:*

Red.is is a good choice if you need a very fast no-sql db, also have a look at mongodb. If you require a multi-region DB I would suggest going with Cassandra or CouchDB due to the partitioned nodes. The image below might help you better decide which DB to use.

[image]